# Error: assembly specified in the dependencies manifest was not found.

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, build, msbuild

When I try to deploy the console core app, I'm getting the error:

Error: assembly specified in the dependencies manifest was not found -- package: 'microsoft.aspnetcore.hosting.abstractions', version: '1.0.0', path: 'lib/netstandard1.3/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Abstractions.dll'

I can see that Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Abstractions.dll exists in  lib/netstandard1.3/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Abstractions.dll. Is there a way to get the path?

Comment: What project type are you using? ( e.g. .NET Core / .NET Framework). How did you deploy the application?

Comment: Are you referring any manifest file to your project? @Dev

Comment: @Martin Ullrich I'm using the .net core . Deployed the application by creating a build definition

Comment: @satish Prabhakaran. How can I check them?

Comment: It looks like I have to include so many nuget packages. All I had included was Microsoft.AspNetCore. Dependencies of Microsoft.AspNetCore should be added manually..

Comment: But what kind of build definition? Does it use `dotnet publish`? which VS version?

Answer (score 0):

If we are using TFS 2013, then the work around was to create a folder and add all the nuget packages required in the folder.

Copy that folder to the server where it has to be deployed and copy all the dlls of the project.

Also change the path in .runtimeconfig.dev.json file in the below variable.

```
  "additionalProbingPaths": [
  "<nugetfolderpath>"
  ]
```

Make sure to use two forward slashes in the path. ex: C:\ProjectName\NugetFolder