# Why .NET Core SCD application doesn't probe assemblies from the same folder?

Tags: c#, .net-core, probing

I created a .NET Core application, and I configured it to copy all of the DLL files to the output directory:

```
  <PropertyGroup>
    <CopyLocalLockFileAssemblies>true</CopyLocalLockFileAssemblies>
  </PropertyGroup>
```

Then for one server, I deployed the `bin\Debug\netcoreapp2.0` folder to the server, installed [.NET Core Windows hosting bundle](https://aka.ms/dotnetcore-2-windowshosting) and things worked just fine.

Yet on another server, I did the same thing and things didn't work and I encountered this [assembly can't be found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48237249/system-security-cryptography-protecteddata-version-4-4-0-can-not-be-found) error.

I went ahead and confirmed that in `dep.json` file there are so many lines of dependencies that somehow guide the runtime to locate them from `runtimes/win/lib/netstandard2.0` folder.

The question is, why doesn't .NET runtime search the existing for the assembly? And how to make it understand that the DLL it's searching for is right there besides the entry assembly and it shouldn't search for it in another location?

Comment: This "configured it to copy all of the DLL files to the output directory" shouldn't be required. The framework knows what dependencies it needs to copy to the output directory. What happens if you remove that property and do a clean and rebuild?

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto, that of course won't deploy any assembly other than our own assemblies. We want to mimic `bin-deployment`, so that a deployment is self-contained.